# Deployed Rails3 but not showing up outside of server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, capistrano, unicorn, mysql2

I just deployed my Rails3 app to a linux server with Capistrano and Unicorn using mysql2. I keep getting the error "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 172.16.128.125" when trying to access the app in a browser.

What is weird is that I see no errors in the ./log/production.log file and if I use lynx on the server, I can render all pages of the app.

What am I missing? It works locally on the server but not outside the server.

Comment: What is the web server in charge with the static content - nginx , thin, apache?

Comment: It seems your nginx/apache is not running, try to start which one you are using

Comment: I added nginx and now get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Working now with nginx installed. Permission errors. Thanks for the leads.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might not have Apache running, or port 80 may not be reachable on that machine due to firewalling or routing issues.